# How to set flag variable if year is changed in comparing two dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

Suppose for example i have start date 31-12-2013 & end date 6-01-2014. i want to set a flag =1  in sql server database table if start date is in previous year & end date is in the next year. how to do this?

Comment: first check start date with current year and than check end date with current year

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using computed column. 
For example, I have created a table with the following script:

```
create table tblcomputedsample
    (start_date datetime,
    end_date datetime,
    Flag As (case when year(end_date) - year(start_date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    )
```

Note the column Flag, which will automatically get the value based on the values in start_date and end_date fields.

Insert some values and check the data.

I inserted some sample data:

```
insert into tblcomputedsample
    values('1-Mar-2014','10-Nov-2014'),('1-Mar-2013','10-Nov-2014'),
              ('1-Mar-2014','10-Nov-2015'),('10-May-2014','20-Dec-2014')
```

and then checked the value of Flag.